# What design pattern would be appropriate when comparing objects

Tags: c#

I recently learned about design patterns and wanted to change my code for a small game I had to make. The game is called [SpaceTaxi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cEcxgPvmQqU). I've made a parser, parsing a .txt file with ascii content resulting in 4 different lists of  entities: taxi, obstacle, exit and platform. Inside the gameloop I call a big  collision-method using these entities detecting whether they collide. It's really ugly code. Is there a good design pattern I could use for my collision method? So instead of having a big method then have smaller classes? Currently it looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
///     Checks for collision with obstacles, platforms and exits.
/// </summary>
private void CollisonCheck() {
    var platformCollision = Player.CollisionPlatform(Parser.PlatformEntities,
        false);
    var obstacleCollision = Player.CollisionObstacle(Parser.ObstacleEntities,
        false);
    var exitCollision = Player.CollisionObstacle(Parser.ExitEntities,
        false);

    // Landing on platform
    if (platformCollision.Item1 && obstacleCollision) {
        // Stand still on platform
        if (Math.Abs(Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.Y)
            < Constants.COLLISION_DISTANCE) {
            Player.Shape.Direction.Y = 0;
            Player.Shape.Direction.X = 0;
            Player.OnPlatform = true;
            // Explode because of too much speed
        } else {
            AddExplosion(Player.Shape.Position.X, Player.Shape.Position.Y,
                0.1f, 0.1f);
        }

        // Be rewarded in case player transports a customer
        if (Player.HasCostumer) {
            foreach (var customer in pickedUpCustomers) {
                if (CorrectDestination(platformCollision.Item2,
                    customer.DestinationPlatform)) {
                    score.AddPoint(CurrentCustomer.RewardPoints);
                    customer.CanRemove = true;
                    Player.HasCostumer = false;
                }
            }
        }

        // Exit map
    } else if (exitCollision) {
        // Switch from one map to another
        if (GameRunning.CurrentMap == "the-beach.txt") {
            GameRunning.CurrentMap = "short-n-sweet.txt";


            Player.SetPosition(Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_X,
                Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_Y);
            Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.Y = Constants.STILL;
            Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.X = Constants.STILL;

            // Switch from one map to another
        } else {
            GameRunning.CurrentMap = "the-beach.txt";
            Player.SetPosition(Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_X,
                Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_Y);
            Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.Y = Constants.STILL;
            Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.X = Constants.STILL;
        }

        GameRunning.Timer.Restart();
        Parser.Load(GameRunning.CurrentMap);

        allCustomersInMap = new List<Customer>();
        foreach (var c in Parser.Customer) {
            allCustomersInMap.Add(new Customer(c.Key, c.Value.Item1,
                c.Value.Item2, c.Value.Item3, c.Value.Item4,
                c.Value.Item5));
        }

        // Collision with obstacle. Add explosion
    } else if (obstacleCollision) {
        AddExplosion(Player.Shape.Position.X, Player.Shape.Position.Y,
            Constants.EXPLOSION_WIDTH, Constants.EXPLOSION_HEIGHT);
        TaxiBus.GetBus()
            .RegisterEvent(GameEventFactory<object>.CreateGameEventForAllProcessors(
                GameEventType.GameStateEvent, this, "CHANGE_STATE",
                "MAIN_MENU", ""));
    }

    // Collision with taxi and customer
    // CollisionCustomer returns a bool (item1) and null/customer (item2)
    if (Player.CollisionCustomer(allCustomersInMap).Item1 && !Player.HasCostumer) {
        var customer = Player.CollisionCustomer(allCustomersInMap).Item2;

        TaxiMeterTimer = new Stopwatch();
        TaxiMeterTimer.Start();

        CurrentCustomer = customer;
        pickedUpCustomers.Add(customer);
        allCustomersInMap.Remove(customer);

        CurrentCustomer.SetPosition(Constants.HIDEPOS_X, Constants.HIDEPOS_Y);
        Player.HasCostumer = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can just extract many methods out of all the `if` conditions and their bodies (their names would be what you now have as comments) so that you end up with clear dependencies and then decide if there is any commonality between the methods to extract them into a class. Such class would be obvious at that point. Your code shows only a small portion of the code with limited surrounding context (what is e.g. `platformCollision.Item1`?) whilst class factoring is usually bound around responsibilities and design which is not easily discernable from what you have at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that questions like this are better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as this is pretty much off topic for SO because you do not have a specific problem or exception that you are trying to resolve.

It is good practise in all applications to separate out decision logic from action logic, for a number of reasons:

- Removing the implementation of actions from complex logic trees makes it easier to visualise the decision process, you assume that the actions work correctly and debug them separately
- Creating single purpose action methods promotes code re-use from different decision logic trees in your program
- You can easily test and debug individual actions or logic branches without disrupting or being distracted by the *bigger picture*.
- You can more clearly document your intent with method Doc Comments

Just separating out the actions you have defined results in code similar to this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Checks for collision with obstacles, platforms and exits.
/// </summary>
private void CollisonCheck()
{
    var platformCollision = Player.CollisionPlatform(Parser.PlatformEntities, false);
    var obstacleCollision = Player.CollisionObstacle(Parser.ObstacleEntities, false);
    var exitCollision = Player.CollisionObstacle(Parser.ExitEntities, false);

    // Landing on platform
    if (platformCollision.Item1 && obstacleCollision)
        DockAtPlatform(); // Stand still on platform
    else if (exitCollision)
        ExitMap(); // Exit map         
    else if (obstacleCollision)
        CollideWithObject(); // Collision with obstacle. Add explosion

    // ??? Player collision can occur at a platform or in general regions in the map
    if (Player.CollisionCustomer(allCustomersInMap).Item1 && !Player.HasCostumer)
        PickupCustomer();
}

/// <summary>
/// Dock Player with platform as long as they are not approaching too fast.
/// Collect reward if carrying a passenger
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>If too fast, player will explode!</remarks>
private void DockAtPlatform()
{
    if (Math.Abs(Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.Y)
        < Constants.COLLISION_DISTANCE)
    {
        Player.Shape.Direction.Y = 0;
        Player.Shape.Direction.X = 0;
        Player.OnPlatform = true;
        // Explode because of too much speed
    }
    else
    {
        AddExplosion(Player.Shape.Position.X, Player.Shape.Position.Y,
            0.1f, 0.1f);
    }

    // Be rewarded in case player transports a customer
    if (Player.HasCostumer)
    {
        foreach (var customer in pickedUpCustomers)
        {
            if (CorrectDestination(platformCollision.Item2,
                customer.DestinationPlatform))
            {
                score.AddPoint(CurrentCustomer.RewardPoints);
                customer.CanRemove = true;
                Player.HasCostumer = false;
            }
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Switch between Maps
/// </summary>
private void ExitMap()
{
    // Switch from one map to another
    if (GameRunning.CurrentMap == "the-beach.txt")
    {
        GameRunning.CurrentMap = "short-n-sweet.txt";


        Player.SetPosition(Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_X,
            Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_Y);
        Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.Y = Constants.STILL;
        Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.X = Constants.STILL;
    }
    else
    {
        // Switch the reverse way around
        GameRunning.CurrentMap = "the-beach.txt";
        Player.SetPosition(Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_X,
            Constants.PLAYER_ENTRYPOSITION_Y);
        Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.Y = Constants.STILL;
        Player.Entity.Shape.AsDynamicShape().Direction.X = Constants.STILL;
    }

    GameRunning.Timer.Restart();
    Parser.Load(GameRunning.CurrentMap);

    allCustomersInMap = new List<Customer>();
    foreach (var c in Parser.Customer)
    {
        allCustomersInMap.Add(new Customer(c.Key, c.Value.Item1,
            c.Value.Item2, c.Value.Item3, c.Value.Item4,
            c.Value.Item5));
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Show explosion because player has collided with an object, then return to the main menu
/// </summary>
private void CollideWithObject()
{
    AddExplosion(Player.Shape.Position.X, Player.Shape.Position.Y,
        Constants.EXPLOSION_WIDTH, Constants.EXPLOSION_HEIGHT);
    TaxiBus.GetBus()
        .RegisterEvent(GameEventFactory<object>.CreateGameEventForAllProcessors(
            GameEventType.GameStateEvent, this, "CHANGE_STATE",
            "MAIN_MENU", ""));
}

/// <summary>
/// Pickup a new customer, start the meter running and remove the customer from the map
/// </summary>
private void PickupCustomer()
{
    var customer = Player.CollisionCustomer(allCustomersInMap).Item2;

    TaxiMeterTimer = new Stopwatch();
    TaxiMeterTimer.Start();

    CurrentCustomer = customer;
    pickedUpCustomers.Add(customer);
    allCustomersInMap.Remove(customer);

    CurrentCustomer.SetPosition(Constants.HIDEPOS_X, Constants.HIDEPOS_Y);
    Player.HasCostumer = true;
}
```

Now you can focus on the individual actions and review them to see if there are cleaner ways to code their process.

### A few notes to consider:

- Add Explosion should accept a point object instead of passing through the X,Y coordinates, it makes the code easier to read and is a natural way to pass coordinates that always go together.
- Instead of using Tuples, you should create specific data model classes to use as return values from the collision functions, it feels like over-engineering, but it helps both with documentation of your code and to understand the intent.

  - Takes little time to define a class to hold the collision response, with minimal documentation, instead of burying inside comments what `.Item1` and `.Item2` might be in terms of data type and logical meaning
  - Yes Tuples are awesome, in terms of rapidly smashing code solutions out, but you always have to review the code that creates the values to understand or identify the meaning behind the values, so these are usually the first to be refactored out of my prototyping code when I want to get serious about a solution.
- You have a style of placing the comments for the next `if` block inside the previous branch code, move the comments to inside the affected if branch, or immediately above it

  - Or move the branch into its own method and you can use Doc comments.
- If the Player object itself holds the meter variables, you could accept multiple passengers (up to the capacity of the vehicle) and collect multiple fares on delivery, your action for dropping off a customer at a platform already assumes multiple passengers.

  - You may have already catered for this in different ways

> **Final Note** (a personal one)
>   Try to change your method logic into more cause and effect style, you gain a lot of benefits in the overall *SDLC* if you adopt more functional programming styles into your OO logic. Where you can, and especially for the smallest units of work, pass in the objects that will be operated on as arguments for your methods rather than referencing global objects, in this way you will find it easier to establish unit testing and code review of your individual methods.
>
> Even though in this project you may not implement unit tests, it is a very good habit to evolve, it will make future code examples that you post on SO easier for the rest of us to debug and will allow you to be a more efficient contributor in a team or community development project.